# Reports for TFS in Agile Environment

Tags: tfs, report, agile

I've just set up reporting capabilities on my TFS 2012, and would like to add reports to it, preferably related to our agile processes.

I remember that back in the days of TFS2008 there were some reports out-of-the-box, provided by Microsoft. But for 2012 version, nothing was installed by default nor I cannot find any reports pack on the web, available for download.

Isn't there any reports available for download anywhere (other than the administrative ones)?

Comment: Which version and edition? Tfs 2012 Express?

Comment: TFS2012 MSDN (Full version)

Comment: Are  you using the Scrum process template, or the Agile? Scrum has no reports, Agile does.

Comment: Did you ever find those? I am also looking for them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using Scrum Process Template, I guess also you talk about the SharePoint Dashboard reports, any you are not talking about reports that exist on the reporting server, if this true.....

Scrum Process Template for SharePoint Dashboard doesn't contain reports, but if you create team project using MSF-For-Agile or MSF-For-CMMI you will find a lot of reports.

Comment: I've just found out about the dashboards in sharepoint, and would love to use them! I have sharepoint integrated with TFS there, but I don't have any dashboards...just a blank sharepoint site. Do I need to install anything special?

Comment: You can review my Guide of TFS 2012 for this part
http://tfs2012visualguide.codeplex.com/

If everything is OK, try to create team projects using other templates MSF-For-Agile or MSF-For-CMMI and let's see what you can see

Comment: Thanks, I had many issues with the Sharepoint (mainly Enterprise vs Standard issues), managed to handle them and now I see the dashboards. We're currently using "Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum" template, no chance I can have the reports with this template? -If I do change the template, will it cause any issue with the work items I currently have?

Comment: You will need to migrate your work-items from the old project to the new one.

Answer (score 1):

I work with the Urban Turtle team and we're currently developing an agile dashboard that embed directly in TFS. We'll release the first version of our Dashboard at the end of this month (february).

It will contain a lot of useful reports to follow your Agile project. If you want to have more information: http://urbanturtle.com/tfs-agile-dashboard/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

try alternative i am not sure that it will work or not.

use

http://tech.lds.org/wiki/LDS_.NET_Stack/TFS_Reports_using_Excel

for manual reporting..